# jQuery UI auto-complete problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the jQuery UI autocomplete widget to work but I'm having some issues.
First, I tried to retrieve some data from the database and store them inside a hidden `<p>` tag in the form of: `item1 ; item2; item3;` and then using jQuery reference this tag and get its content using `.html()` (result was null) or `.text()` (result was empty string). Then I decided to do all of this locally inside the jQuery block and did the following:

```
var tags = "house ; children's room ; master bedroom ... etc"
    alert(tags); //returns them in the right format
    var availableTags = tags.split(' ;');
    alert(availableTags); //returns them in the form" item1, item2, item3
    alert(availableTags[1]); //returns children's room
    $(".liTagInput").autocomplete({ 
        minLength: 2,
        source: availableTags 
    });
```

But that still doesn't get the autocomplete to work... Why is it not working? I made sure I added the CSS as well, so that shouldn't be the problem...

Theoretically, I would still want to retrieve the data from the database. In this instance, I would want just echo the tags to the html page and then do as described at the beginning. In other cases where the result could be too big, I would want to get them via AJAX but that's another story... I need to get this to work first and then I'll worry about that more complex scenarios :)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo works as coded here: http://jsfiddle.net/aXuHq/

Some other tips:

- Did you inspect the hidden element you're appending the items to to make sure the contents are what you expect?
- You could also just `echo` the tags into a JavaScript array (not sure what server-side technology you're using so I won't be able to provide an example), and pass that directly to autocomplete.
- Using AJAX with autocomplete isn't too bad to set up, check out the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).

Comment: I have just figured it out. The problem was because the autocomplete was being called on an element that is not yet available in the DOM. I added the above code to the callback function of the `show()` function which makes thw 'wizard page' appear and that solved the problem... :)